# Чем отличается constexpr от const constinit?

Tags: c++, c++20, объявление

Чем отличаются объявления в глобальном пространстве имён?

```
const constinit auto x = 42;
constexpr auto y = 42;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Духсообщества какие детали необходимы? Вроде бы всё ясно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конкретно эти ничем не отличаются, даже если убрать `constinit`, потому что `const` целочисленные переменные с constexpr инициализатором автоматически становятся constexpr.

В общем случае, разница, конечно, есть.

`constinit` максимум вызывает ошибку компиляции, если инициализатор не constexpr. А если constexpr, то он ничего не делает<sup>1</sup>, поэтому разница такая же, как между `const` и `constexpr` переменными.

---

Интересная особенность - `constinit` проверяет только инициализацию на constexpr-ность, а `constexpr` дополнительно проверяет деструктор.

---

<sup>1</sup> Не считая хитрой оптимизации для `thread_local` переменных: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constinit

Comment: Не совсем понял разницу. "constinit максимум вызывает ошибку компиляции, если инициализатор не constexpr" — но ведь `constexpr` тоже её вызывает. "А если constexpr, то он ничего не делает" — а что делает `constexpr` в отличие от `constinit`?

Comment: Тип может быть любым, не только `int`, но объявления находятся в глобальном пространстве имён.

Comment: @rumeo `constinit` - подмножество `constexpr`. Последний дополнительно делает переменную `const`, и, главное, разрешает использовать эту переменную в constexpr-выражениях.

Comment: Но если `const constinit`, то дополнительный `const` уже есть. А если глобальное пространство имён, то можно использовать в constexpr-выражении. То есть в таком контексте разницы между `const constinit` и `constexpr` нет?

Comment: @rumeo *"если const constinit, то дополнительный const уже есть"* Верно. *"если глобальное пространство имён, то можно использовать в constexpr-выражении"* Нет, откуда вы это взяли? Максимум ее адрес можно использовать в constexpr-выражении. Например, сделайте функцию, которая читает число через `cin` и возвращает его. Потом сделайте глобальную переменную `int x = foo();` - явно же не constexpr.

Comment: Но ведь мы не сможем сделать `const constinit int x = foo()`, точно так же как и `constexpr int x = foo()`. Вот это имею в виду.

Comment: Другими словами, есть ли ситуации когда `const constinit` и `constexpr` в глобальном пространстве имён для любых типов приведут к разным результатам?

Comment: @rumeo Так, еще раз. Разница в том, что `const constinit` нельзя использовать в constexpr-выражениях, если тип не целочисленный - можете проверить. Интереснее, почему это так. На [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constinit) пишут еще одно дополнительное требование, которое `constexpr` проверяет, а `const constinit` нет - чтобы деструктор можно было вызвать во время компиляции. Наверное в этом дело.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat constinit дает статическую или потоковую длительность хранения, даже без const и во всех контекстах, афайк.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Тогда уж не "дает", а "требует".

Comment: или гарантирует своими требованиями, наверно так.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat теперь понял. Думаю, стоит добавить последний коммент в ответ.